# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL

Tags: php, email

I am recieveing a syntax error, unexpected T_SL at the EOD.  From what i have been reading it's normally from extra spaces/tabs/white space.  In this case there are none.  I have even hard coded the email and was still receiving the error.  I have tried placing the end of the EOD on another line with no spaces and still doesn't work.  Any other ideas?

```
$emailSubject = 'crazy php scripting!';
$webMaster = 'someEmail@yahoo.com';
$email = 'someEmail@live.com';
/* This is the line i get errors from. */
$body = <<<EOD<br><hr><br>Email:{$email}<br>EOD;  
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this line

```
$body = <<<EOD<br><hr><br>Email:{$email}<br>EOD;
```

to:

```
$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>Email:{$email}<br>
EOD;
```

Because [heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) symbol should be at beginning of the new line